# Looking for a one-liner to remove duplicate multiline paragraphs from a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
File:
this is a paragraph
to find in another 
file

some stuff .. 

more stuff ... 

this is a paragraph
to find in another 
file

more stuff ... 

another paragraph 
to match

yet more stuff.. 

this is a paragraph
duplicate in this 
file

another paragraph 
to match 

this is a paragraph
duplicate in this 
file

yet more stuff..

this is a paragraph
to find in another
file
```

should return:

```
this is a paragraph
to find in another 
file

some stuff .. 

more stuff ... 

more stuff ... 

another paragraph 
to match

yet more stuff.. 

this is a paragraph
duplicate in this 
file

yet more stuff..
```

I have found pcregrep -n -M, I know I could loop around and search each paragraph using sed and this command but pcregrep is not on every system so if it can be avoided that would be good. Looking for something elegant using the standard *nix stuff and preferably not perl.

*** Some good posts and ideas but they didn't work generally though did on the limited case that I posted, so I have adjusted the example data so you can see if it will work more generally

*** Here is a sed one-liner that prints multiple line paragraphs only:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/.*\n.*\n.*/!d' file
```

Comment: I printed the wrong output, but it still doesn't work due to the last output, the latest version does: awk -v RS= '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+$/,""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]+\n/,"\n")} !seen[$0]++{ORS=RT;print}' - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mostly does what you want. The only problem (I know of offhand) is that it collapses runs of blank lines in the input into a single blank line in the output.

```
awk -v RS= '!x[$0]++{print; print ""}'
```

Use the fact that "If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines." and print out an extra blank line for the `RS` that awk swallowed.

Edit: Incorporating @EdMorton's suggestions gets you this instead.

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!seen[$0]++'
```

And `awk -v RS= '!seen[$0]++{ORS=RT; print}'` for GNU awk to keep spacing between paragraphs consistent with the input (instead of collapsing runs of blank lines).

Edit again:

This version seems to work correctly (with GNU awk 3.1.7 and newer, I don't know about 3.1.6) with the one exception that it adds a blank line to the end of the file.

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+$/,""); gsub(/[[:blank:]]+\n/,"\n")} !seen[$0]++{ORS=RT;print}'
```

Comment: +1: You can use `-vORS="\n\n"` instead of two `print` statements. Though that may be just a matter of preference.

Comment: @jaypal I didn't think of that but I didn't think of `printf "%s\n\n",$0` but didn't think it was worth changing to use that. `ORS` is cleaner though.

Comment: Good idea it worked on the original example data I posted but I was looking for something more general, I adjusted the example data. Sorry about that I thought it was a waste of space at first to put such a long sample data.

Comment: @A.Danischewski Why do the `more stuff ...` and `yet more stuff..` lines show up in your desired output? What makes them different than `this is a paragraph`?

Comment: Actually it would be fine if they were also removed but the point of the question is really how to eliminate multiline patterns, the single line duplicates are already handled by various standard tools.

Comment: This awk script does handle multiline duplicates. I'm confused as to what you think it isn't handling correctly. The only difference between your given desired output and the output of my awk script on your input is the duplication of those two lines I just asked about in your output that mine removes.

Comment: This is a `perl` equivalent. `perl -00 -ne'$h{$_}++ or print' file`. The `awk` should work too. You should post data that is not getting filtered by the script Etan has provided, other wise we are all just wasting time.

Comment: @jaypal Both the awk script and the perl one-liner you posted duplicate the entry (this is a paragraph\n to find in another\n
file) and the other duplicate is (another paragraph\nto match)

Comment: @jaypal & Etan. The problem OP is having is that there are spaces at the end of some lines meaning they are not exact duplicates and so appear to be printed twice. Piping from `sed 's/ *$//' file` will solve the problem.

Comment: +1 for the right approach but set ORS as @jaypal suggested rather than 2 explicit prints, and put a space between `-v` and the variable you're setting as not putting a space makes it needlessly gawk-specific. Also, the array `x` is most commonly/idiomatically named `seen` for clarity. So the script should be `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!seen[$0]++' file`. If reproducing the number of blank lines between each paragraph is required then you can set `ORS=RT` inside the action block with GNU awk. To get rid of trailing blanks, prefix with `{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+\n/,"\n")}` (no need for sed).

Comment: @Jidder The problem I have with this is that it doesn't remove all duplicates, I posted my results above in the question for clarity.

Comment: @A.Danischewski Ah. I always delete trailing spaces when I paste since I am never sure if they were supposed to be there. Yes, without doing that this "doesn't work as desired" because it "works as designed" and those two things don't match up. EdMorton provides the solution for looking for duplicates without caring about trailing spaces. Though it isn't clear to me that that's the right behaviour in this case.

Comment: @EdMorton That `gsub` doesn't appear to be working (GNU awk 3.1.5). I can't get it to match against `\n` correctly in those records. `[[:blank:]]+` works and `[[:blank:]]$` works but `[[:blank:]]+\n` fails to match anything. It does seem to work in 3.1.7 and 4.1.1 though.

Comment: The only way that will fail is if you don't have any blanks at the end of your lines or if your awk is broken. Sounds like you're experiencing the latter!